# Azure Tables - Partition Key and Row Key - Correct Choice

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am new to Azure tables and having read a lot of articles but would like some reassurance on the above given its fundamental.

I have data which is similar to this:

```
CustomerId, GUID
TripId, GUID
JourneyStep, GUID
Time, DataTime
AverageSpeed, int
```

Based on what I have read, is `CustomerId` a good PartitionKey?  Where I become stuck is the combination of `CustomerId` and `TripId` that does not make a unique row.  My justification for `TripId` as the Row Key is because every query will be a dataset based on `CustomerId` and `TripId`.

Just for context, the `CustomerId` is clearly unique, the `TripId` represents one journey in a vehicle and within that journey the `JourneyStep` represents a unit within that Trip which may be 10 steps or 1000.

The intention is aggregate the data into further tables with each level being used for a different purpose.  At the most aggregated level, the customer will be given some scores.

The amount of data will obviously be huge so need to think about query performance from the outset.

**Updated:**

As requested, the solution is for Vehicle Telematics so think of yourself in your own car.  Blackbox shipping data to an server which in turn passes it to Azure Tables.  In Relational DB terms, I would have a Customer Table and a trip table with a foreign key back to the customer table.

The `tripId` is auto generated by the blackbox.  `TripId` does not need stored by date time from a query point of view, however may be relevant from a query performance point of view.

Queries will be split into two:

1. Display a map of a single journey for each customer, so filter by customer and then Trip to then iterate each row (journeystep) to a map.
2. Per customer, I will score each trip and then retrieve trips for, let's say, the last month to aggregate a score.  I do have SQL Database to enrich data with client records etc but for the volume data (the trip data) I wish to use Azure Tables.

The aggregates from the second query will probably be stored in a separate table, so if someone made 10 trips in one month, I would run the second query which would score each trip, then produce a score for all trips that month and store both answers so potentially a table of trip aggregates and a table of monthly aggregates.

Comment: For a particular `CustomerId` will `TripId` be unique?

Comment: Gaurav, No - one customer will have multiple trips.  The only unique combination would be CustomerId and Time but from a query point of view would rarely be used.   'the combination of CustomerId and TripId does not make a unique row'

Comment: Then unfortunately you can't use TripId as RowKey. Within a Partition, RowKey has to be unique.

Comment: Ah, that is what I feared.  If I use Time for the RowID which is unique, what is the best approach for query performance given every query will be including TripID?  I could append something to the TripId to make a unique Row Key but I would want to split them out in very query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design has to be related to your query.  You can filter your data based on 2 columns PartitionKey and RowKey.  PartitionKey is your most important column since your queries will hit that column first.

In your case `CustomerId` should be your *PartitionKey* since most of the time you will try to reach your data based on the customer. (you may also need to keep another table for your client list)

Now, RowKey can be your `tripId` or `time`.  if I were you I probably use rowKey as `yyyyMMddHHmm|tripId` format which will let you to query based on startWith and endWidth options.

Comment: Thanks Cilerler, solution wise this seems appropriate for what I want.  As the tripId is a guid, it is easy to do a starts with/ends with approach, is that sensible from a query performance point of view?  Going Frans route seems to be doable also, but I would have to join to the customer table every time which seems suboptimal?

Comment: @SteveNewton it is actually depends on your needs.  I mean if you are dealing with Expedia kind of site, you will need to go Customer First, Trip Second kind of approach.  But in your case you may need oposite of that.  It is really depends on how big your data will be and how will you need to access that data.

Comment: By the way, about "I would have to join to the customer table every time which seems suboptimal" part.  Many documents tell that as long as you have PrimaryKey in your hand your query will be fast enough (if you have both Primary+Row it will perform best) But remember we don't have GetAllPartitionKeys() method yet which means YOU MUST keep another table as yyyyMMddHHmmssfffff OR numeric Id as PartitionKey and ClientId as RowKey in order to get general reports like GetAllTrips()

Answer (score 3):

The thing about the Partition Key is that it represents a logical grouping; You cannot insert data spanning multiple partition keys, for example. Similarly, rows with the same partition are likely to be stored on the same server, making it quick to retrieve all the data for a given partition key.

As such, it is important to look at your domain and figure out what aggregate you are likely to work with.

If I understand your domain model correctly, I would actually be tempted to use the TripId as the Partition Key and the JourneyStep as the Row Key. 
You will need to, separately, have a table that lists all the Trip IDs that belongs to a given Customer - which sort of makes sense as you probably want to store some data, such as "trip name" etc in such a table anyway.

Comment: Thanks Frans, have read up this afternoon and have gone with the approach of Cilerler, so marked his answer as the Answer.  For anyone else reading, this answer is not incorrect but the other seemed more appropriate to my situation.

Comment: @Steve No worries, it all depends on your domain and query needs. Glad you found a solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Frans answer:

One thing you could do is create a separate table for each customer. So you could have table named like Customer. That way each customer's data is nicely segregated into different tables. Then you could use `TripId` as `PartitionKey` and then `JourneyStep` as `RowKey` as suggested by @Frans. For storing some metadata about the trip, instead of going into a separate table, I would still use the same table but here I would keep the RowKey as empty and put other information about the trip there.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I think we have two valid approaches, the secondary part of the question is which one provides the best query performance given the quantity of data will be huge!  Lets say 100gb for arguments sake, the design at this point is critical.  I will always query against a customer and trip.

Comment: Before I could answer the question, I have some more questions of my own :) - 1) Will you know the `TripId` in advance? 2) Do the `TripId` need to be sorted by date/time? It would certainly help if you could elaborate your querying requirements in your original post.

Comment: Updated my original post hopefully clarifying my query requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest considering the following approach to your PK/RK design.  I believe it would yield the best performance for your outlined queries:

PartitionKey: combination of CustomerId and TripId.

```
string.Format("{0}_{1}", customerId.ToString(), tripId.ToString())
```

RowKey: combination of the DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - Time.Ticks formatted to a large 0-padded string with the JourneyStep.

```
string.Format("{0}_{1}", (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - Time.Ticks).ToString("00000000000000000"), JourneyStep.ToString())
```

Such combination will allow you to do the following queries "quickly".

- Get data by CustomerId only.  Example: `context.Trips.Where(n=>string.Compare(id + "_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", n.PartitionKey) <= 0 && string.Compare(id+"_zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz") >=0).AsTableServiceQuery(context);`
- Get data by CustomerId and TripId. Example: `context.Trips.Where(n=>n.PartitionKey == string.Format("{0}_{1}", customerId, tripId).AsTableServiceQuery(context);`
- Get last X amount of journey steps if you were to search by either CustomerId or CustomerId/TripId by using the "Take" function
- Get data via date-range queries by translating timestamps into Ticks
- Save data into a trip with a single storage transaction (assuming you have less than 100 steps)

If you can guarantee uniqueness of Times of Steps within each Trip, you don't even have to put JourneyStep into the RowKey as it is somewhat inconvenient

The only downside to this schema is not being able to retrieve a particular single journey step without knowing its Time and Id.  However, unless you have very specific use cases, downloading all of the steps inside a trip and then picking a particular one from the list should not be so bad.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Igorek, a very thorough answer and certainly one I will build into my research.

Answer (score 1):

The design of table storage is a function to optimize two major capabilities of Azure Tables:

- Scalability
- Search performance

As @Frans user already pointed out, Azure tables uses the partitionkey to decide how to scale out your data on multiple storage server nodes. Because of this, I would advise against having unique partitionkeys, since in theory, you will have Azure spanning out storage nodes that will be able to serve one customer only. I say "in theory" because, in practice, Azure uses smart algorithms to identify if there are patterns in your partitionkeys and thus be able to group them (example, if your ids are consecutive numbers). You don't want to fall into this scenario because the scalability of your storage will be unpredictable and at the hands of obscure algorithms that will be making those decisions. See [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx) for more information about scalability.

Regarding performance, the fastest way to search is to hit both partitionkey+rowkey in your search queries. Contrary to Amazon DynamoDB, Azure Tables does not support secondary column indexes. If you have your search queries search for attributes stored in columns apart from those two, Azure will need to do a full table scan.

I faced a situation similar to yours, where the design of the partition/row keys was not trivial. In the end, we expanded our data model to include more information so we could design our table in such a way that ~80% of all search queries can be matched to partition+row keys, while the remaining 20% require a table scan. We decided to include the user's location, so our partition key is the user's country and the rowkey is a customer unique ID. This means our data model had to be expanded to include the user's country, which was not a big deal. Maybe you can do the same thing? Group your customers by segment, or by location, or by email address SMTP domain?